# Launching code from view: View immediately after launching the app

Tags: android, function, kotlin, apk

**How can I run code that needs the view: View argument immediately after launching the app?** For example, change the text `mytext.text = "Hello World!"` immediately after launch? How can I do this if I need a function with the arguments view: View, but the function can't run itself. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a Handler and tell it after some milli seconds do an action for you after the launch :

```
Handler().postDelayed({
            myView.text = "some text"
        }, 1000)//1 second
```

if you are using an activity use it in onCreate()
and if you are using a fragment use it in onCreateView()